# Resources for current thought on time/spacetime?

Tags: spacetime, time

Are any of the big-name physicists associated with the time in the same way that Hawking and Penrose are associated with black holes? I'm interested in some good books that focus on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hawking has his *Brief History of Time*, which also deals with some aspects of time. There is a reason it is called spacetime and they are interconnected. Another book I enjoyed is B*lack Holes and Time Warps* by Kip Thorne. There is also the usual suspects of Briane Greene and Lisa Randell

Comment: Funny - I've got all of those books. I guess I should check my own library first!

Comment: I dont know how advanced you are, but the arxiv has enough ideas (most border on crackpot theories) on these things. There is also Itzhak Bars, he has a two time theory

Comment: a brief history of time by sean carroll

Answer (score 2):

The big-name Blogger-Physicist who has most recently published about time, AFAIK, is Sean Carroll, who can be found at Cosmic Variance. The current blog entry, as of now, is http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/cosmicvariance/2011/11/08/a-cornucopia-of-time-talks/, which may also give you an alternative start into the topic. Or you can Google for "Sean Carroll time", which, amongst others, will get you to his web-page of the book, http://preposterousuniverse.com/eternitytohere/. He's been on The Colbert Report, which you can see there, than which there is no greater recommendation.

I would hope that the citations in Carroll's book would get you to much of the more significant recent work, but if you chase references very far you will get as much nonsense as not.